# Django signals how properly connect sender with receiver

Tags: django, django-signals

I faced with problem while trying to play with django signals. I have a project with following structure

```
authexample
manage.py 
posts #django app 
func.py #here is sender and receiver logic is realised
```

In posts app's models.py  i created a simple post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     body = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In my `func.py` which is located outside post app i realised my signals calling logic by following code

```
from django.db.models import models
from posts.models import Post 
from django.db.models.signals import post_save 
from django.dispatch import receiver 

#my sender function  
def func_sender(title,body):
    a = Post(title=title,body=body)
    a.save()

#receiver function 
@receiver(post_save, sender=func_sender)
def func_receiver(sender,**kwargs):
    print("article was saved")
```

Than i am trying to create test article for this purposes i run

```
python manage.py shell 
from func import * 
a = Post("test_title","test_body)
```

When this code was executed my test article was created but i expect that after article was created my receiver function `func_receiver` will execute and prompt me string inside print statement. Why this isn't occur. Guide me please

Answer (score 0):

After googling i found solution. My problem was because when i called receiver in sender keyword argument i specified `func_sender` but proper way was specify model Post itself. And here is my solution

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=Post)
 def func_receiver(sender,**kwargs):
      print("post was saved)
```